# $B_n\to A$ and $B_n \in \mathfrak M_F(\mu)$ implies $A\in \mathfrak M_F(\mu)$ ? (Rudin's Theorem 11.10)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I'm new to measure theory.  I was reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, and wasn't so sure why he said on Page 308 that

> Hence $B_n\to A$; and since $B_n \in \mathfrak M_F(\mu)$, it is easily seen that $A\in \mathfrak M_F(\mu),$

where $\mathfrak M_F(\mu)$ denotes *finitely $\mu-$measurable sets*, i.e. $A\in \mathfrak M_F(\mu)$ if there is a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of *elementary sets* such that $A_n \to A.$

My attempt to justify it is the following: To show $A \in \mathfrak M_F(\mu)$, I construct a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of elementary sets such that $d(A_n, A)<\frac{1}{n}$ as follows.  For each $n$, first find an index $k_n$ such that $d(A, B_{k_n})<\frac{1}{2n}$. (This can be done since $B_n \to A.$)  Then we find an elementary set $A_n$ such that $d(B_{k_n}, A_n) < \frac1{2n}.$  (This is feasible because each $B_n \in \mathfrak M_F(\mu).$)  As a result, we have $d(A, A_n)<\frac1{n},$ which shows $A_n\to A$ and hence $A\in \mathfrak M_F(\mu).$

Is the above argument correct?  Are there better ways to see/prove it?  Thanks a lot!